Removing element at index 0, throws IndexOutOfRangeException but array not empty
To process data in a large array that is being filled fast, I made few threads to process it in parallel. Deleting the first element and logging the result has to be synchronised so I used AutoResetEvent.
The issue is that at some point, when deleting the element, it throws an error that the 0 index is out of range even though it has elements in it. I have no idea how this is happening.
private void InitializeProcessingThreads()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++)
    {
        ares[i] = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        int index = i;
        threads[i] = new Thread(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    if (BigArray.Count < index + 1)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("BigArray is smaller than " + (index + 1));
                        continue;
                    }
                    byte[] data = BigArray[index];
                    Processing(data);
                    // do other processing here
                    if (index > 0)
                    {
                        ares[index - 1].WaitOne();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ares[numberOfThreads - 1].WaitOne();
                    }
                    Debug.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " Completed processing");
                    if (BigArray.Count != 0)
                        BigArray.RemoveAt(0);   // Or call another thread to remove all the packets and do some general work
                    ares[index].Set();
                    if (index > 0)
                    {
                        ares[index - 1].Reset();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ares[numberOfThreads - 1].Reset();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + ", " + BigArray.Count + ", " + e);
                throw;
            }

        });
        threads[i].Name = "Thread" + i;
    }
    ares[numberOfThreads - 1].Set();
}

This circularly runs for ever.
I have no idea how this is happening. I tried to remove element only if size of array is not zero but it still runs and gives an error.

What is BigArray?

Based on the code it seems that it is List, which 1) is not a thread safe collection so should not be modified from different threads  2) will change index space on removal (i.e. if you remove some element it shifts everything).

You can avoid most of these complexities by using a thread-safe collection, e.g. ConcurrentQueue or possibly BlockingCollection depending on your need. These will take care of the locks for you.

It looks like you need to use another solution for your task. Instead of deleting elements, use the array as a circular buffer with pointers to the first element and to the last element.
This will not only relieve you of the problem described but will also increase productivity.
Use a single object to maintain the buffer for multithreading purposes. Create a dispatcher method to queue requests and allocate the appropriate number of elements per request.

I also think a different kind of storage is needed. But instead of trying to write it by yourself, better take some existing like a ConcurrentQueue.

@Oliver Sure, there are some alternatives.
